# How to integrate $\int\limits_0^1 \left(-1\right)^{^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

As my title says, I need help integrating with floor functions,

$$\int\limits_0^1 \left(-1\right)^{^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}} dx$$

What does this even mean exactly? How would approach this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Essentially, you have this:
$$\int_0^1 \left(-1\right)^{^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}} dx=\int_\frac{1}{2}^1\left(-1\right)^1dx+\int_\frac{1}{3}^\frac{1}{2}\left(-1\right)^2dx+\int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{3}\left(-1\right)^3dx+\int_\frac{1}{5}^\frac{1}{4}\left(-1\right)^4dx+\ldots$$
$$=\left(-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+ \left(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\ldots$$
$$=-1+2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\ldots\right)$$
$$=-1+2(1-\log2)=1-\log 4$$

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

One may write 
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \left(-1\right)^{\large ^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}}  \mathrm{d}x  
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}}  \left(-1\right)^{\large ^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}}  \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} \left(-1\right)^{\large ^{\left\lfloor u\right\rfloor}} \: \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{u^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} \left(-1\right)^{{k}} \: \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{u^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{{k}}}{k (k+1)} \\
&=  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{k+1}\\
&=-\log 2-\log 2+1
\end{align*} where we have used the standard identity
$$
\log(1+x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}x^k, \quad |x|<1,
$$ when  $x \to 1^-$ (via [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem)).

Finally,

> $$\int_{0}^{1} \left(-1\right)^{\large ^{\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor}}  \mathrm{d}x  
> = 1-2 \log 2.
> $$

Comment: (+1), I think that you could integrate just after the third equality! :)

Comment: @H.R. Right! I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: Just a question bumped in my head! How can we rigorously prove the first equality!? I mean it is a limit and it needs some justification although the intuition says it is OK. :)

Comment: One may just see it from $$ (0,1]=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}[1/(k+1),1/k]$$ No?

Comment: I think you are right! :) In fact, I was thinking for a proof of this identity! :)

Comment: A proof: each element in the left hand side set is in the right hand side set, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. :) I think my problem is that a limit for a real valued function is defined in my mind (for example via $\varepsilon-\delta$) but not for union of sets! I even don't know what it means! This is maybe due to my lack of knowledge in some elementary concepts. :) To be more percise, how do we define

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cup_{k=1}^{n}[1/(k+1),1/k]$$

Comment: The infinite union of sets has been defined as given here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Arbitrary_unions    But all these concepts are not so trivial...